# Getting a label to insert text slowly

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to insert text to a lable, BUT the text has to be inserted slowly/character by character/letter by letter,
kinda like in old MUD games.

So far I have tried doing this:

```
private void StoryBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = StoryBox.Text;
    var index = 0;
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);

    timer.Elapsed += delegate
    {
        if (index < text.Length)
        {
            index++;
            StoryBox.Text = "This should come out pretty slowly ";
        }
        else
        {
             timer.Enabled = false;
             timer.Dispose();
        }
    };

    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

This is what I have gathered from the site but I don't particularly understand why this isn't working.

As you can see it's under `StoryBox_Click`.
Is there a way to automate this? So when the program is opened, it counts a couple seconds and THEN starts writing the text out.

Comment: What do you mean with slowly ? Do you mean letter by letter ?

Comment: @Youssef13 Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string yourText = "This should come out pretty slowly";
    label1.Text = string.Empty;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= yourText.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        label1.Text += yourText[i];
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Shown`-Event of `YourForm` when you want to start it after your GUI has been opened.

So reusing your provided code and changing a few things this may work for you:

Add private fields to `YourForm` class:

```
private Timer _timer;
private int _index;
private string _storyText;
```

and initialising it in `YourForm` constructor

```
public YourForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // init private fields;
    this._index = 0;
    this._storyText = "This should come out pretty slowly";

    // Timer Interval is set to 1 second
    this._timer = new Timer { Interval = 1000 };

    // Adding EventHandler to Shown Event
    this.Shown += this.YourForm_Shown;

    this._timer.Tick += delegate
    {
        if (this._index < this._storyText.Length)
        {
            StoryBox.Text += this._storyText[this._index];
            this._index++;
        }
        else
        {
            this._timer.Stop();
        }
    };
}
```

and the `Shown` event for `YourForm`:

```
private void YourForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this._timer.Start();
}
```